# Unauthorizedaccessexception: how to wait on input from user. Windows Phone c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone

Here I am working on creating a simple practice windows phone app that simulates a guessing game. I have a while loop that runs the game until the user guesses the correct answer; what I want to do is at the beginning of each loop, wait for the user to trigger an event from pressing enter in the textbox. I'm new to this idea and have no experience in multi-threading.
I am getting an unauthorizedaccessexception, and I'm not sure what is causing it.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Random r;
    int guess;
    static AutoResetEvent autoEvent;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        r = new Random();
        autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Thread t = new Thread(PlayGuessGame);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void PlayGuessGame()
    {
        bool hasWon = false;
        int secretNumber = r.Next(1, 3);
        int tries = 1;

        messageTextBox.Text = "Guess a number";

        while (!hasWon)
        {
            autoEvent.WaitOne();
            if (guess == secretNumber) //if user wins
            {
                messageTextBox.Text = "Congratulations! You've guess the correct number! It took {0} tries.";

            }
            else
            {
                tries++;
                if (guess < secretNumber)
                    messageTextBox.Text = "Guess higher!";
                else
                    messageTextBox.Text = "Guess lower!";

                lastGuessTextBox.Text = guess.ToString();
            }

        }
    }

    private void guessTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            guess = int.Parse(guessTextBox.Text);
            autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mind adding the stack trace you are receiving?

Comment: Where do i get the stack trace from in visual studios?

Comment: Why are you using a loop like this in a GUI application? Why not manage the state of the game and just handle the button press event?

Comment: Your right Brian, I should just use even handlers for the control. But while I'm thinking here, I want to understand what my problem is here, so I can improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is because you are trying to access an object from a thread it wasn't created by.  So the thread that is running your PlayGuessGame() isn't supposed to play in that sandbox.  You can get around this though by using a MethodInvoder:

```
        private void PlayGuessGame()
    {
        bool hasWon = false;
        int secretNumber = r.Next(1, 3);
        int tries = 1;

        messageTextBox.Text = "Guess a number";

        while (!hasWon)
        {
            autoEvent.WaitOne();
            if (guess == secretNumber) //if user wins
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { messageTextBox.Text = "Congratulations! You've guess the correct number! It took {0} tries."; }));

            }
            else
            {
                tries++;
                if (guess < secretNumber)
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { messageTextBox.Text = "Guess higher!"; }));
                else
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { messageTextBox.Text = "Guess lower!"; }));

                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lastGuessTextBox.Text = guess.ToString(); }));
            }

        }
    }
```

I would definitely recommend Brian Warshaw's comment, this should be an event driven GUI.  Hope this helped though, you could use this elsewhere you are using threads!